# How to use Istio Virtual Service in-between front and back services

Tags: kubernetes, proxy, istio

I am totally new to Istio, and the pitch looks very exciting. However, I can't make it work, which probably means I don't use it properly.
My goal is to implement session affinity between 2 services, this is why originally I end up using Istio. However, I do a very basic test, and it does not seem to work:
I have an kubernetes demo app which as a front service, a stateful-service, and a stateless service. From a browser, I access the front-service which dispatches the request either on the stateful or stateless services, using K8s service names as url: http://api-stateful or http://api-stateless.

I want to declare a virtual service to intercept requests sent from the front-service to the stateful-service.I don't declare it as a gateway, as I understood gateway was at the external border of the K8s cluster.
I use Docker on Windows with Istio 1.6.

I copy my yaml file below. the basic test I want to do: reroute traffic for api-stateful to api-stateless, to validate that the Virtual Service is taken into account. And it does not work. Do you see what is wrong? Is it a wrong usage of Virtual Service ? My Kiali console does not detect any problem in setup.

```
####################################################################
######################### STATEFUL BACKEND #########################
# Deployment for pocbackend containers, listening on port 3000
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: stateful-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: stateful-backend
      tier: backend
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: stateful-backend
        tier: backend
    spec:
       containers:
       - name: pocbackend
         image: pocbackend:2.0
         ports:
           - name: http
             containerPort: 3000
---
# Service for Stateful containers, listening on port 3000
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: api-stateful
spec:
  selector:
    app: stateful-backend
    tier: backend
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 3002
    targetPort: http
---
#####################################################################
######################### STATELESS BACKEND #########################
# Deployment for pocbackend containers, listening on port 3000
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: stateless-backend
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: stateless-backend
      tier: backend
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: stateless-backend
        tier: backend
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: pocbackend
        image: pocbackend:2.0        
        ports:
           - name: http
             containerPort: 3000
 ---
# Service for Stateless containers, listening on port 3000
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
 metadata:
  name: api-stateless
spec:
  selector:
    app: stateless-backend
    tier: backend
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 3001
    targetPort: http
---
#############################################################
######################### FRONT END #########################
# deployment of the container pocfrontend listening to port 3500
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: front-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: frontend
      tier: frontend
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: frontend
        tier: frontend
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: pocfrontend
        image: pocfrontend:2.0               
        ports:
           - name: http
             containerPort: 3500      
---
# Service exposing frontend on node port 85
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: frontend-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: frontend
    tier: frontend
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 3500
    targetPort: http
    nodePort: 30000
---
##############################################################
############ ISTIO PROXY FOR API-STATEFUL SERVIC E############
##############################################################
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: api-stateful-proxy
spec:
  hosts:
  - api-stateful
  http: 
  - route:
      - destination:
          host: api-stateless
```

Comment: with this virtual service you are sending the request to the stateful service, and it will route to stateless. besides, what do you mean with doesn't work?

Comment: stateless and stateful services for now return a counter value, nothing fancy. Every time a pod receives a request, it generates a log in a stateful or stateless folder (I removed the volumemounts from my example to keep it short). Despite my virtual service, when I send a request to the stateful-service, it IS the stateful-service which receives the request, not the stateless-service: so it appears the virtual service does not do tthe routing properly or is by-passed. I was just testing routing by Virtual Service.

Comment: You mean I need to target api-stateful-proxy? That's not consistent with the documentation, plus the "hosts" part of the Virtual Service is supposed to specify which host the request targets.

Comment: You are right. That was wrong.

Comment: Have You tried adding `DesinationRule` with sticky session configuration? In istio documentation it can be found on [this](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/destination-rule/#LoadBalancerSettings) page.

Comment: @PiotrMalec, I actually solved my problem with DestinationRule, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in comments this can be fixed with `DestinationRule` with sticky session configuration.

Example of that can be found in istio [documentation](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/destination-rule/#LoadBalancerSettings):

> ### LoadBalancerSettings
>
> Load balancing policies to apply for a specific destination. See Envoy’s load balancing  [documentation](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/intro/arch_overview/upstream/load_balancing/load_balancing)  for more details.
>
> For example, the following rule uses a round robin load balancing policy for all traffic going to the ratings service.
>
> ```yaml
> apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
> kind: DestinationRule
> metadata:
>   name: bookinfo-ratings
> spec:
>   host: ratings.prod.svc.cluster.local
>   trafficPolicy:
>     loadBalancer:
>       simple: ROUND_ROBIN
> ```
>
> The following example sets up sticky sessions for the ratings service hashing-based load balancer for the same ratings service using the the User cookie as the hash key.
>
> ```yaml
>  apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
>  kind: DestinationRule
>  metadata:
>    name: bookinfo-ratings
>  spec:
>    host: ratings.prod.svc.cluster.local
>    trafficPolicy:
>      loadBalancer:
>        consistentHash:
>          httpCookie:
>            name: user
>            ttl: 0s
> ```

Comment: thanks, I agree, I finally did like that. I was curious about VirtualService, I never figured how it worked and this is why I let the post opened and unanswered. Anyway you are perfectly right and it works, thanks!